# How to show only Gmail's contacts in the Contacts app?

Tags: contacts, 2.3-gingerbread, gmail, google

I have recently reinstalled Android on B63M due to some problems with the SD Card. I decided to keep all my contacts **only** in Gmail, as a centralized solution to avoid problems in the future. I do **not** want other SIM or phone contacts to show in the contacts list anymore.

However, if I try to uncheck both the SIM and phone contacts and I *do* check all possible Google contacts groups <s>and the option for showing only contacts with a phone number</s><sup>1</sup>, **no** contact is shown at all. If I also show the phone contacts, then the Google contacts *are* shown (and thus I have some duplicates), but removing the phone contacts removes the Google contacts too.

Note that **the contacts are perfectly synched and all under the *My contacts* group**. It's **not** a synchronisation problem. I'm asking why I *must* select the *show phone contacts* in order to see *any* contact at all (from whichever source you like. Even SIM. I *cannot* show only the SIM contacts without the *show phone contacts* enabled.)

To make things clearer, here are some screenshots of the situation:

Here I have set *only* the phone contacts (*Contatti del telefono* in Italian), without Google contacts:

[image: Screenshot of contacts App showing the phone contacts and related options]

Here I have added the Google contacts in the options *and they are shown* (see red rectangles. Note the number of contacts at the top going from 116 to 156):

[image: Screenshot of contacts App showing the phone and the google contacts and related options]

Now, I'd expect that removing the phone contacts I should see only the Google contacts (in this case those that above have red rectangles and the other not shown), but this is what I get:

[image: Screenshot of the contacts App not showing any contact and related options saying to show only (and all) Google contacts]

On the right, it just says that there are no contacts to show and that I can add new contacts or import/export from other sources.

What should I do such that this last set of options *does* show the Google contacts?

---

<sup>1</sup> Having or not this option active doesn't change anything. Even if it is not active no contact is shown.

Comment: Go for third-party contacts apps to avoid further problems...

Comment: @SachinShekhar Which one? I'd expect a good contacts App to: 1) Require less than 0.5 MB of storage, 2) Provide *all* functionality of the built-in application (without bugs) 3) No useless permissions/features 4) Free 5) No ads. If you know any application that fulfils these requisites then I'd consider your answer.

Comment: Try EX dialer.... Its lightweight and it provides more features than stock contacts app. But, its over 1.5MB which you can tradeoff.

Comment: @Bakuriu: Unfortunately, the stock Contact app is crappy when it comes to this sort of thing. Under **Contacts to display** menu option there is a cog-wheel icon at the bottom of the screen which give you some option to display your contacts based on a given Gmail email address. It may or may not be what you want. Have a look anyway...

Comment: @ChuongPham I don't see any wheel in the option menu. Maybe you are using a newer version of Android.

Comment: I'm using JellyBean, stock Android, and the cog-wheel icon is next to the **Customised List** option. It's the last option shown when you choose **Contacts to display**.

Comment: The contacts app is pretty rubbish, try downloading a few and see if any of them suit your needs.

Comment: @RossC Actually I find the contacts app quite intuitive. The *only* thing where it fails is what I have described here. If you know some better contact app that could suit my needs you can answer this question. By the way: downvoters: please explain since I believe I did everything possible to clarify what I'm asking.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend any particular app as I do understand your needs, but the actual execution varies wildly in these apps. I'm using the new google dialer (the one built into search) and for every good point theres a few things I really don't like. I never use any contacts app I just dial them directly so it isn't an issue for me. http://www.tomshardware.com/news/address-book-apps-dialer-apps-third-party-speed-dial,20492.html Maybe one of these will help. The best bet, to my mind, is to try a few and find what you like!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to get the [Gmail app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gm&hl=en) from the Play Store.

Answer (score 0):

First, type any number(s), select the save option, then it will show you blank field options. Along with those fields, find the option (it will be on top) or drop-down like embedded menu depending on the Android phone model. The blank fields to save will change upon selecting the type of field you selected.

Second, by default, it will be in SIM or phone or your email by the time you're checking which else is there the option in that only contacts are saved.

Thirdly, for saved contacts, go to Contacts > Options. There scroll and find "Contacts to display". I hope your problem must have been solved.

**Procedure is correct, but options may vary or be located in different ways by different manufacturers**

Finally, coming to other handsets like Karbon, Celkon, Micromax, so-called Chinese handsets in India. Previously, it is found that they don't have any proper sync options. For example, in costlier and top-brand handsets, contacts sync with G+, FB, etc., and give users suggestions to choose contacts still in social & chat apps where else it is not that much we can expect on unknown handsets. What I mean to tell you is contacts matching nearly to your already saved.

The easiest way if possible is to add contacts directly from Gmail on a PC. But you need to log in with the email you're using and require sync in mobile check contacts after logout.

Recently, it has been seen that contacts are directly saved to Viber, Telegram, etc., and not synced with any other app or phone.

Answer (score -1):

Go to `Contacts > [Sitting Button] > More > Accounts`.

Be sure the following are checked:

1. Background data.
2. Auto-sync.

Comment: I'd -1 this answer but unfortunately I don't have enough reputation. As I have already stated in the question **contacts are synched**. I have both auto-synch and background data active, and I have manually asked for a synchronization *multiple times*. This is **not** a problem about synchronisation. It's the App not displaying data that it **does** have available.

Answer (score -2):

`Contacts/People > Menu > Contacts to Display > select your gmail account` to display.

Comment: I'd -1 this answer but unfortunately I don't have enough reputation. I'm asking this question *exactly* because what you describe does **not** work.